# Are VueJS2 data variable values and methods hackable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Are VueJS2 data variables values and methods hackable?

If a Firebase/Firestore connection is set up and the db updating runs over a Vue method which when called, updates a value in the db from a Vue data variable, could a user hack it? If so, how?

Comment: vue is java script and js is client side / user side. means you give it to user

Comment: Anything on the client can be modified by the user.

Comment: An authenticated firebase user can do anything you allowed his user to do. It doesn't matter what you do client-side